# How to select three adjacent table cells (one by one) vertically or horizontally without overlaps?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have the table below and some style to it. I need a way to use JavaScript to allow the user to click on 3 adjacent cells one by one, in a straight line, vertically or horizontally without overlapping.

It is a complicated condition but basically it requires clicking on 9 cells in total, 3 groups of 3 cells which are in a straight line, either horizontally or vertically. The 3 groups of 3 cells could be directly next to each other as long as they don't overlap. Only when all 3 adjacent cells in a group are selected, then the user can select the location for the next group.

If the user doesn't follow the conditions to select an adjacent cell after the first one in a group, he could be notified by alert to select a correct cell.

The cells are going to change color when clicked, just like in the image.

[image]

```
<table id="board">

        <tr id="a">
          <td id="a1"></td>
          <td id="a2"></td>
          <td id="a3"></td>
          <td id="a4"></td>
          <td id="a5"></td>
          <td id="a6"></td>
          <td id="a7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="b">
          <td id="b1"></td>
          <td id="b2"></td>
          <td id="b3"></td>
          <td id="b4"></td>
          <td id="b5"></td>
          <td id="b6"></td>
          <td id="b7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="c">
          <td id="c1"></td>
          <td id="c2"></td>
          <td id="c3"></td>
          <td id="c4"></td>
          <td id="c5"></td>
          <td id="c6"></td>
          <td id="c7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="d">
          <td id="d1"></td>
          <td id="d2"></td>
          <td id="d3"></td>
          <td id="d4"></td>
          <td id="d5"></td>
          <td id="d6"></td>
          <td id="d7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="e">
          <td id="e1"></td>
          <td id="e2"></td>
          <td id="e3"></td>
          <td id="e4"></td>
          <td id="e5"></td>
          <td id="e6"></td>
          <td id="e7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="f">
          <td id="f1"></td>
          <td id="f2"></td>
          <td id="f3"></td>
          <td id="f4"></td>
          <td id="f5"></td>
          <td id="f6"></td>
          <td id="f7"></td>
        </tr><tr id="g">
          <td id="g1"></td>
          <td id="g2"></td>
          <td id="g3"></td>
          <td id="g4"></td>
          <td id="g5"></td>
          <td id="g6"></td>
          <td id="g7"></td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

I've been stuck with this for 2 hours now, trying to find a solution. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Change your id-s to r1c1 indicating row 1 column 1. It will be easy to track. I could help you more if you share what you have tried so far.

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I couldn't think of a condition that works for more than one cell :((

Comment: Do user need to click continuously the first 3 cells in an vertical or horizontal order. If user click say r1c1 and you highlight it. Next he click r3c4 which is not adjacent to r1c1. So do u unhighlight the r1c1 or not

Comment: If the user doesn't follow the condition to select an adjacent cell after the first one in a group, he could be notified by alert to select a correct cell.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question.

Comment: do you want to force the user to click adjacent cells or is it ok to click as long as the cells lie on a straight line vertically or horizontally? It seems the later approach would be more user friendly

Comment: I do not understand what you mean? They should be adjacent cells that lie in a straight line vertically or horizontally. The attached image explains what the result should/could be.

Comment: let's say for the first group of 3 cells, does the user have to click 1,1; 1,2; and then 1,3 or could he click 1,2; 1,1 and then 1,3? Also, do you want to force the user to complete selecting one group before moving on to the next?

Comment: Oh, I see now. Yes, preferably the user should complete the group before starting another one because I think this would be easier to code.

Comment: is the board always 7x7?  and clicking 1,1 1,3 and then 1,2 is ok?

Comment: Yes, the board is always 7x7. If it solves the problem and produces the same result as in the image, yes it would be ok.

Comment: here's a link to get you started  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rss81/8gkczwt2/)

Comment: Thank you! I am beginner tho so it is hard for me to understand the JavaScript part. However, it gives me one idea I may try.

Comment: I've been working on this for you and have made some progress. here's a link to an updated fiddled:** [NEW FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rss81/8gkczwt2/336/)** The question I have is what do you want to happen if the user clicks on a cell that's already been clicked? We can a)ignore, b) popup an alert or c) undo the selection and make it show as unselected –

Comment: Thank you so much, this is awesome. About the question, I think we can just ignore repeated clicks on the same cell.

Comment: ok, here's where I am.  goodspaces1checked is written and is run when we have the first click for each group of three.  We still need to write goodspaces2checked and goodspaces3checked.  Why don't you give those a try and see what you can come up with.  Comment back if you need more help.  here's the latest fiddle: [LATEST FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rss81/8gkczwt2/402/)

Comment: alright, I'll give it a try.

Comment: this new fiddle takes out the ability to undo a click:  [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rss81/8gkczwt2/406/)

Comment: @mihailm, how's it going?  do you understand the code?

Comment: yeah, i think I found a way to do it.

Comment: @mihailm did you get this to work?

Comment: @mihailm the provided solution works but it could be better.  As it is it's not generic and can't be easily adjusted to account for a different size board, different number of groups, and different number of cells per group.  I think using recursion could address these issues and provide a more elegant solution.  But as they say, if it aint broke don't fix it.

Comment: @DCR Absolutely agree! I almost got my version of it to work as well but there was one collision bug that I just couldn't fix, so I had to switch to a bit more "primitive" method. I see your solution works perfectly with no bugs. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function tdClick(e) {
if(!alldone){
   var row = e.target.id.substring(0,1).charCodeAt() - 96;
   var col = e.target.id.substring(1,2) * 1;
   
   curClick = [row,col];   

   var isClicked = false;
   for (var i = 1; i<4; i++){     
      for (var j = 1;j<4;j++){                  
         if(cellsClicked[i][j][1] == row && 
            cellsClicked[i][j][2] == col) {
               isClicked=true;
             //  click = j;
             //  group = i;
          }
      }
   }         

   if(isClicked){   
      if (1==2){ //this code used to unclick a button
         cellsClicked[group][click][1] = 0;
         cellsClicked[group][click][2] = 0;
         e.target.classList.remove('checked');
         e.target.classList.add('okToCheck');
         click--;
         if(click == 0){
            group--;
            if(group == 0) group = 1;         
         }
      }
   }else if (group+click != 6){ 
     
      if(e.target.classList.contains('okToCheck')){
         click++;
         if (click == 4){
            click = 1;
            group++;            
            if (group == 4) {
                group = 3;
                click = 3;
            }
         }
         cellsClicked[group][click][1] = row;
         cellsClicked[group][click][2] = col;      
         e.target.classList.add('checked');
         e.target.classList.remove('okToCheck');
      }
   }else{
      alldone=true;
   }
   
   //console.log('click:'+click+' group:'+group);
   
   if(click == 1 && !softClick[0])goodspaces1checked(row,col);
   if(click == 2 && !softClick[1])goodspaces2checked(row,col);
   if(click == 3)goodspaces3checked();
}else{
 //3 groups selected
}
}

function goodspaces1checked(row,col){   
   goodSpaces=[];
   var cnt = 0;
   softClick[0] = true;

   var chr = String.fromCharCode(96 + row );
   var id = chr+(col-1);   
   var TD = document.getElementById(id);
   var oneLeft = true;
   if(TD === null || TD.classList.contains('checked'))oneLeft=false;   

   chr = String.fromCharCode(96 + row );
   id = chr+(col+1);
   TD = document.getElementById(id);
   var oneRight = true;
   if(TD === null || TD.classList.contains('checked'))oneRight=false;

   chr = String.fromCharCode(96 + row );
   id = chr+(col+2);
   TD = document.getElementById(id);
   var twoRight = true;
   if(TD === null || TD.classList.contains('checked') || !oneRight)twoRight=false;

   chr = String.fromCharCode(96 + row );
   id = chr+(col-2);
   TD = document.getElementById(id);
   var twoLeft = true;
   if(TD === null || TD.classList.contains('checked') || !oneLeft)twoLeft=false;

   chr = String.fromCharCode(96 + row - 1);
   id = chr+col;
   TD = document.getElementById(id);
   var oneDown = true;
   if(TD === null || TD.classList.contains('checked'))oneDown=false;

   chr = String.fromCharCode(96 + row + 1);
   id = chr+col;
   TD = document.getElementById(id);
   var oneUp = true;
   if(TD === null || TD.classList.contains('checked'))oneUp=false;

   chr = String.fromCharCode(96 + row + 2);
   id = chr+col;
   TD = document.getElementById(id);
   var twoUp = true;
   if(TD === null || TD.classList.contains('checked') || !oneUp)twoUp=false;

   chr = String.fromCharCode(96 + row - 2);
   id = chr+col;
   TD = document.getElementById(id);
   var twoDown = true;
   if(TD === null || TD.classList.contains('checked') || !oneDown)twoDown=false;

   if(oneLeft && oneRight){
      goodSpaces[cnt] = [row,col-1];
      goodSpaces[cnt+1] = [row,col+1];
      cnt=cnt+2;
   }
   if(twoRight){
      goodSpaces[cnt] = [row,col+1];
      goodSpaces[cnt+1] = [row,col+2]
      cnt=cnt +2;
   }
   if(twoLeft){
      goodSpaces[cnt] = [row,col-1];
      goodSpaces[cnt+1] = [row,col-2]
      cnt=cnt+2;
   }
   
   if(oneUp && oneDown){
      goodSpaces[cnt] = [row+1,col];
      goodSpaces[cnt+1] = [row-1,col];
      cnt=cnt+2;
   }
   if(twoUp){
      goodSpaces[cnt] = [row+1,col];
      goodSpaces[cnt+1] = [row+2,col]
      cnt=cnt +2;
   }
   if(twoDown){
      goodSpaces[cnt] = [row-1,col];
      goodSpaces[cnt+1] = [row-2,col]
      cnt=cnt+2;
   }
  
    
    nodupes();   
   
    goodSpaces.forEach(function(element) {
      chr = String.fromCharCode(96 + element[0]);
      id = chr+element[1];      
      TD = document.getElementById(id);
      TD.classList.remove('okToCheck');      
      TD.classList.add('okToCheckNow');//placeholder     
     /*
        console.log(TD.id);
        TD.classList.forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element);
        });
     */     
    });
    
    for(var i=1;i<8;i++){
       for(var j=1;j<8;j++){
          chr = String.fromCharCode(96 + i);
          id = chr+j;
          TD = document.getElementById(id);
          if(TD.classList.contains('okToCheck')){
             TD.classList.remove('okToCheck');
             TD.classList.add('notOkToCheck');          
          }else if(TD.classList.contains('okToCheckNow')){    
             TD.classList.remove('okToCheckNow');
             TD.classList.add('okToCheck');       
          }
       }
    }
    
    
}

function goodspaces2checked(row,col){ 
    softClick[1]=true;
    var len = goodSpaces.length;
    var i;
    
   // oldSpaces = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(goodSpaces));
      oldSpaces=clone(goodSpaces);
        
    if(row == cellsClicked[group][1][1]){ /*2nd click on same row*/       
       if(Math.abs(col - cellsClicked[group][1][2]) == 1){/* 2nd click adjacent */          
          for(i = 0;i<len;i++){          
             if (goodSpaces[i][0] != row || 
                Math.abs(goodSpaces[i][1] - col) == 3 || 
                (goodSpaces[i][0] == row && goodSpaces[i][1] == col)){
                   goodSpaces[i][0] = 0;
             }
          }          
       }else if(col > cellsClicked[group][1][2]){/*middle cell*/
          for(i = 0;i<len;i++){           
             if ( (goodSpaces[i][0] != row || goodSpaces[i][1] != col-1)){       
                goodSpaces[i][0]=0;
             } 
          }
       }else{
          for(i = 0;i<len;i++){           
             if (goodSpaces[i][0] != row || goodSpaces[i][1] != col+1){       
                goodSpaces[i][0]=0;                  
             } 
          }       
       }
    }else{ /*2nd click on same col*/       
       if(Math.abs(row - cellsClicked[group][1][1]) == 1){/* 2nd click adjacent */          
          for(i = 0;i<len;i++){          
             if (goodSpaces[i][1] != col || 
                Math.abs(goodSpaces[i][0] - row) == 3 || 
                (goodSpaces[i][1] == col && goodSpaces[i][0] == row)){
                   goodSpaces[i][0] = 0;
             }
          }          
       }else if(row > cellsClicked[group][1][1]){/*middle cell*/
          for(i = 0;i<len;i++){            
             if ( (goodSpaces[i][1] != col || goodSpaces[i][0] != row-1)){       
                goodSpaces[i][0]=0;
             } 
          }
       }else{
          for(i = 0;i<len;i++){          
             if (goodSpaces[i][1] != col || goodSpaces[i][0] != row+1){       
                goodSpaces[i][0]=0;                  
             } 
          }       
       }
     }
     
    goodSpaces = goodSpaces.filter(function(space){
       return space[0] != 0;   
    });
 
   
/*    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
       if(goodSpaces[i][0]==0){
          goodSpaces.splice(i, 1);          
          len--;
          i--;
          goodSpaces = Object.values(goodSpaces);
       }
    } 
*/  
    var flag = true
    oldSpaces.forEach(function(oldSpace,index){
       flag = true;
       goodSpaces.forEach(function(goodSpace){
          if(oldSpace[0] == goodSpace[0] && oldSpace[1] == goodSpace[1])flag=false;
       });
       if(flag){           
          chr = String.fromCharCode(96 + oldSpaces[index][0]);
          id = chr+oldSpaces[index][1];
          TD = document.getElementById(id);
          if(TD.classList.contains('okToCheck')){
             TD.classList.remove('okToCheck');
             TD.classList.add('notOkToCheck');  
          }
       }
    });    
}
function goodspaces3checked(){
softClick=[false,false,false];

var check = false

for (var i=1;i<8;i++){
   for (var j=1;j<8;j++){
   check = false;
   
      for(var k = 1;k<4;k++){
         for (var m = 1;m<4;m++){
            if(cellsClicked[k][m][0] == i && cellsClicked[k][m][1] == j)check = true;
         }
      }
      if(!check){
          chr = String.fromCharCode(96 + i);
          id = chr+j;
          TD = document.getElementById(id);
          if(TD.classList.contains('notOkToCheck')){
             TD.classList.remove('notOkToCheck');
             TD.classList.add('okToCheck');  
          }     
      }  
   }
}
   //the first two groups of 3 can block out the squares near each corner
   if(group == 2 && click == 3){
      cellsToBlock=[[1,1],[2,1],[1,2],[2,2],
                    [7,1],[6,1],[7,2],[6,2],
                    [7,7],[6,7],[7,6],[6,6],
                    [1,7],[2,7],[1,6],[2,6]];
              
      var cords=[];              
      cords[0]=[[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[3,1]];
      cords[1]=[[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[4,1]];
      cords[2]=[[1,3],[1,4],[2,2],[3,2]];
      cords[3]=[[2,3],[2,3],[3,2],[3,2]];
 
      cords[4]=[[7,2],[7,3],[6,1],[5,1]];
      cords[5]=[[6,2],[6,3],[5,1],[4,1]];
      cords[6]=[[7,3],[7,4],[6,2],[5,2]];
      cords[7]=[[6,3],[6,3],[5,2],[5,2]];
 
      cords[8]=[[7,6],[7,5],[6,7],[5,7]];
      cords[9]=[[6,6],[6,5],[5,7],[4,7]];
      cords[10]=[[7,5],[7,4],[6,6],[5,6]];
      cords[11]=[[6,5],[6,5],[5,6],[5,6]];

      cords[12]=[[1,6],[1,5],[2,7],[3,7]];
      cords[13]=[[2,6],[2,5],[3,7],[4,7]];
      cords[14]=[[1,5],[1,4],[2,6],[3,6]];
      cords[15]=[[2,5],[2,5],[3,6],[3,6]];

      var cellblock=false;

      for( i = 0;i<16;i++){
         cellbock = false;
         cellblock=checkcell(cords[i]);
         if (cellblock)blockcell(cellsToBlock[i]);
      }
   }
}

function blockcell(cell){
   var chr = String.fromCharCode(96 + cell[0]);
   var id = chr+cell[1];
   var TD = document.getElementById(id);
          if(TD.classList.contains('okToCheck')){
             TD.classList.remove('okToCheck');
             TD.classList.add('notOkToCheck');  
          }     

}

function checkcell(cords){
cord1 = cords[0];
cord2 = cords[1];
cord3 = cords[2];
cord4 = cords[3];

blk1 = false;
blk2 = false;
blk3 = false;
blk4 = false;

for (var i=1;i<4;i++){
   for (var j=1;j<4;j++){
   
      if(cellsClicked[i][j][1] == cord1[0] &&
         cellsClicked[i][j][2] == cord1[1]) blk1 = true;
      
      if(cellsClicked[i][j][1] == cord2[0] &&
         cellsClicked[i][j][2] == cord2[1]) blk2 = true;
       
      if(cellsClicked[i][j][1] == cord3[0] &&
         cellsClicked[i][j][2] == cord3[1]) blk3 = true;
      
      if(cellsClicked[i][j][1] == cord4[0] &&
         cellsClicked[i][j][2] == cord4[1]) blk4 = true;
   }
}

 if((blk1 || blk2) && (blk3 || blk4)) return true;
 else return false;


}

function nodupes(){

   var len = goodSpaces.length;
   for (var i=0;i<len-1;i++){
      for(var j=i+1;j<len;j++){
         if (goodSpaces[i][0] == goodSpaces[j][0] && 
             goodSpaces[i][1] == goodSpaces[j][1]){
             goodSpaces[j][0] = 0;
             goodSpaces[j][1] = 0;
         }      
      }
   }
   
   
   
   goodSpaces= goodSpaces.filter(function(space){
      return space[0] != 0;   
   });
   
   

/*   for(i=0;i<len;i++){      
       if (goodSpaces[i][0] == 0){           
          goodSpaces.splice(i, 1);          
          len--;
          i--;
          goodSpaces = Object.values(goodSpaces);
       }
   }   
*/}
function clone(obj) {
    var copy;

    // Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;

    // Handle Date
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
        copy = new Date();
        copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Array
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        copy = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
            copy[i] = clone(obj[i]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Object
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        copy = {};
        for (var attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = clone(obj[attr]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
}



var myboard = document.getElementById("board");




myboard.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "TD") {
    tdClick(e);
  }
});


var goodSpaces = [];
var oldSpaces= [];
var softClick = [false,false,false];
var group = 1;
var click = 0;
var cellsClicked=[];
var alldone = false;

var lastClick=[0,0];
var curClick=[0,0]


for (var i = 1; i<4; i++){
     cellsClicked[i] = [];
   for (var j = 1;j<4;j++){
       cellsClicked[i][j]=[]   
      for (var k=1;k<3;k++){            
           cellsClicked[i][j][k] =0;
           
      }
   }
}
```

```css
td{
  width:60px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:white;
  color:white;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
}

table{
   margin:0 auto;
   border:1px solid black;
   }






.okToCheck{
  color:white;
  background-color:white;
}
.okToCheck:hover{
  background-color:lightgrey;
}

.notOkToCheck{
  color:#bfbfbf;
  background-color:#bfbfbf;
 }
 
 .checked{
   background-color:grey;
   color:grey;
   
 }
```

```html
<div>
<table id="board">
  <tr id="a">
    <td id="a1" class="okToCheck">a1</td>
    <td id="a2" class="okToCheck">a2</td>
    <td id="a3" class="okToCheck">a3</td>
    <td id="a4" class="okToCheck">a4</td>
    <td id="a5" class="okToCheck">a5</td>
    <td id="a6" class="okToCheck">a6</td>
    <td id="a7" class="okToCheck">a7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="b">
    <td id="b1" class="okToCheck">b1</td>
    <td id="b2" class="okToCheck">b2</td>
    <td id="b3" class="okToCheck">b3</td>
    <td id="b4" class="okToCheck">b4</td>
    <td id="b5" class="okToCheck">b5</td>
    <td id="b6" class="okToCheck">b6</td>
    <td id="b7" class="okToCheck">b7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="c">
    <td id="c1" class="okToCheck">c1</td>
    <td id="c2" class="okToCheck">c2</td>
    <td id="c3" class="okToCheck">c3</td>
    <td id="c4" class="okToCheck">c4</td>
    <td id="c5" class="okToCheck">c5</td>
    <td id="c6" class="okToCheck">c6</td>
    <td id="c7" class="okToCheck">c7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="d">
    <td id="d1" class="okToCheck">d1</td>
    <td id="d2" class="okToCheck">d2</td>
    <td id="d3" class="okToCheck">d3</td>
    <td id="d4" class="okToCheck">d4</td>
    <td id="d5" class="okToCheck">d5</td>
    <td id="d6" class="okToCheck">d6</td>
    <td id="d7" class="okToCheck">d7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="e">
    <td id="e1" class="okToCheck">e1</td>
    <td id="e2" class="okToCheck">e2</td>
    <td id="e3" class="okToCheck">e3</td>
    <td id="e4" class="okToCheck">e4</td>
    <td id="e5" class="okToCheck">e5</td>
    <td id="e6" class="okToCheck">e6</td>
    <td id="e7" class="okToCheck">e7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="f">
    <td id="f1" class="okToCheck">f1</td>
    <td id="f2" class="okToCheck">f2</td>
    <td id="f3" class="okToCheck">f3</td>
    <td id="f4" class="okToCheck">f4</td>
    <td id="f5" class="okToCheck">f5</td>
    <td id="f6" class="okToCheck">f6</td>
    <td id="f7" class="okToCheck">f7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="g">
    <td id="g1" class="okToCheck">g1</td>
    <td id="g2" class="okToCheck">g2</td>
    <td id="g3" class="okToCheck">g3</td>
    <td id="g4" class="okToCheck">g4</td>
    <td id="g5" class="okToCheck">g5</td>
    <td id="g6" class="okToCheck">g6</td>
    <td id="g7" class="okToCheck">g7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In the table, let `<td>` have custom data attributes with `data-row="" data-column=""`
2. when user clicks the `<td>`, on click of element check element's data-row and data-column
3. if it is already clicked, unhighlight else highlight it and store the value in an result array as "row"+"column" i.e., 11.
4. On next selection, repeat steps 1-3. Before adding to the result array. check the number "row"+"column"
   suppose the `result = [11];`
   current `selection = 12;`
   here this is valid, because the difference between the previous and current is 1
   the other valid entry will be if it 21, where the difference is 10.

So, this way check if the current is vertically or horizontally adjacent.
If it is valid add it to the array. Else,
Empty the array and unhighlight the previous selection and add this to the array.

After the entry into array check the length of array. if it is 3, it means 3 selections are made and put it into main array.

Here, after this whenever next selection is made it has to be checked the current selection does not overlap with the main array list.

This is the basic algorithm that need to constructed.

Try to code according to this. And if any problems in code, I will be happy to help.